# jquery load in IE

Tags: jquery

I have a success function within a .click() function

in the success function I have

```
    $('#div').load('page.php?id' + id);
```

The click function is a 'LIKE' button, people can like and unlike..

Works fine in all browser except for IE9 and previous.

In IE it only works once: Someone clicks on button and the div on side of page refreshes

with new like info, however if they click on it again (unlike) without refreshing page it no longer works.

Any Ideas?

Many Thanks !

Edit: The actual LIKE button works fine, the LIKE - UNLIKE cycle works.

It's the actual div with page.php loaded into it which only works once (it's a sort of counter).

Comment: @David: I've seen IE be really aggressive with the browser cache. Try disabling the cache or clearing it before every click to see if that changes anything

Comment: @Andrew: clearing browser cache does work. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Can you create an example page the replicates the issue?

Comment: @NeXXeuS: give me 2 minutes..

Comment: Have you put a random variable in the url? Like calling page.php?id=1234&time=32142343 will usually prevent the page from caching (the time is the real time in seconds, different on every ajax call).

Comment: ^ This is a good idea as well.

Comment: @user399696 You should make it an answer. ;)

Comment: @user399696:Sorry didn't work, ended up doing this: `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // will always be outdated` On page.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with `$.get` and I bet it'll work just fine:

```
$.get('page.php?id' + id, {}, function(result) {
    $('#div').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today and fixed it by putting

```
$.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
```

right before the call to jQuery.load(...).

Answer (score 0):

this my way. you can try it.

use $.ajax instead load() method. like this ,you must set cache:false.

```
    $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:'M=P',
    cache:false,        
    // async:false,
    success:function(text){
        box.html(text);
        return false;
    }

    });
```